# laravel-dompdf how to get multiple records into the data array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, dompdf

I have this code to try to generate a report on all records in a table:

```
$items = Line::all();
$data = $items->toArray();
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.catalogue', $data);
return $pdf->stream();
```

How do I access the array in my Blade template? I have tried
    @foreach ($data as $item)
but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

How you usually pass these variables into blade is by a named array, meaning you would assign it as so.

```
$data['items'] = $items->toArray();
```

In your template you should have the variables $items containing the array.

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: No this is not right. You can pass the data in that way but then you cannot do @foreach($items as $item), instead you have to do @for ($x-1;$x<count($items) etc and refer to the data line using $item['title'] type notation, which loses all the Laravel relationships.

Comment: @JonathanHyams sorry, I don't normally overwrite blade with some other view templating. That's how you pass it normally when doing view->make

Comment: I wonder if you are talking about Laravel 4? I don't agree with you re Laravel 5, sorry.

Comment: I mean you don't have to agree with me, check the documentation. It's default blade behavior. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views | http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade You're changing the view composer to use dompdf so you're not using blade you're using dompdf's version of blade.

Comment: view->make is Laravel 4.

Comment: New syntax for Laravel 5:

    public function home() {
        return view('home');
    }

Comment: The actual facade is still the same. You're just using a helper in laravel 5, you're also not getting the point of how to push variables to the view. Which is (regardless of syntax) is a possible data variable after the view name.